# Dynamics CRM 2016 authentication scope

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm

I am having issues authenticating a user with Azure to work with a CRM2016 on Premise instance. A token is created, but doesn't actually grant permission to access anything, I get 401s or error page html depending on the specifics of the token generation request when making subsequent calls with the token.

While I'm looking at other possible problems, this struck me as odd in the return body of the token generation request.

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"User.Read","expires_in":"3599","ext_expires_in":"0","expires_on":"1507718481","not_before":"1507714581","resource":"<snip>","access_token": "<snip"}
```

The scope value seems to be implying that the only access I've been given is to read the user's profile. Am I reading that right?

If so how would I go about fixing that? All the documentation I read implies that being authenticated as a user gives you all their permissions. Would this be some kind of conflict between the user's permissions on the Azure instance and the CRM? (I'm new to Microsofts business applications, I'm not certain how users are shared between the two).

Comment: Are you sure the user is granted any security roles in CRM? `User.Read` is basically the only privilege granted without a security role.

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes, everything is ticked in the assign roles dialog

Comment: Since your CRM is on-premise, you can [turn on server-side tracing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/907490/how-to-enable-tracing-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm) and get verbose details about the errors thrown. There are also a [nice gui tools](http://mscrmtools.blogspot.de/2013/09/new-tool-trace-reader-for-microsoft.html) to turn on/off tracing and examine the logs on codeplex. **WARNING:** Do never forget to turn off tracing when you're done! Even on dev or test systems with low traffic logs will fill your drive in no time!